# Adjusting Title in UITableViewCell Xcode StoryBoard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, xcode-storyboard

I want to move the position of the title textview in my cell prototype.  When I select the "Title" I cannot adjust the X,Y coordinates or even the Width and Height.  Are we not allowed to customize this part of the cell.

When I tried to do this in code it said I was not allowed to access the current parameter. How do I move the location of this title and subtitle.  I want to move it to the top of the cell and have my colored views below.  Thanks in advance, still somewhat new to Xcode.

```
   cell.textLabel.frame.origin.x = 30;  //not allowed to access
```

[image]

Comment: You can't do this with Apples UITableViewCell prototypes. You simply have to create a custom cell instead of subtitle. Drag and drop some labels anywhere into that you want and subclass it to create the outlets and to be able to reference it

Comment: Tutorials are everywhere. Here's an example http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Comment: I think that solved my problem, I realized once I switched to custom, I had the freedom I wanted,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot access to the x position, but you can put the whole frame easily. 
Here and example all by code, I think It's your best option:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *reuseIdentifier = @"reuseIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (!cell)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    cell.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, 30);
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];


}
// Configure your cell...


return cell;
}
```

Here using Story cell, I think is worse because more work.(It didn't take advantage for the reuse technology at all).

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {



UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"storyIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];


cell.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, 30);
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];



// Configure your cell...


return cell;
}
```